# Electron: How to access .Net COM Objects

Tags: node.js, electron, win32ole

I am trying to create a simple application using Electron quick start. its going to be run on windows 10 where I need to access few .Net COM objects installed on that machine.

When I google about this I am directed to [win32ole](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole) package that needs to be installed, but I see that this is 4 years old and it doesn't install on my windows 10 machine.

I was wondering if any one has ever managed to access the COM servers from within the Electron Node.js code? or if you have any opinion on how to go about this requirements.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT or https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge